# Метростанция/метро-станция

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

> Метростанция, на которой мы встретимся, — «Звенигородская», сиреневая.

> Метро-станция, на которой мы встретимся, — «Звенигородская», сиреневая.

А здесь?

> Метролиния.

> Метро-линия.

Comment: Образец: метеостанция.

Comment: Леопольд, я изменил ответ. Вам может не понравиться, но всë в соответствии с фактами. В общем, принимать или не принимать — ваше решение, но всë в соответствии с правилами.

Comment: Иностранные слова, хоть они заимствованные, хоть пришлые, вносят путаницу. Чем не устраивает русское слово "остановка"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно:

***Метростанция,** на которой мы встретимся, — «Звенигородская», сиреневая.*

**Большой толковый словарь**

МЕТРО, неизм.; ср. = Метрополитен. Петербургское м. Ехать в м. Станция м. Войти в м.

МЕТРО... Первая часть сложных слов. Обозначает **отнесённость к метро, метрополитену.** Метровагон, метролиния, метромост, метропоезд.

Орфографический словарь: ***метролиния, метромост.***

Неверно: ***метро-станция, метро-линия.***  Такого слова нет с словаре.

Но слова "метростанция" тоже нет? Да, нечастотный вариант, но **модель образования** подобных слов обозначена.

**Нацкорпус:**

*Ну, в начале прошлого века, когда в метро пассажиров было в десять раз меньше, может быть, этой естественной вентиляции в тоннелях, где, как поршни в насосе, двигались поезда, и хватало, но я разговорился с бронзовыми фигурами **на метростанции** "Площадь Революции", и они жаловались: в иные минуты просто нечем дышать!*  Сергей Есин. Маркиз Астольф де Кюстин. Почта духов, или Россия в 2007 году.

Answer (score 0):

*Станция метро, на которой мы встретимся, — «Звенигородская», сиреневая*.

Ни слова *метростанция*, ни слова *метро-станция* нет ни в каком словаре. + фото:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А слово *метролиния* как раз существует:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Вывод: *станция метро, метролиния*.

Comment: Мне *кажется*, Максим, что из ваших изысканий надо было сделать такой вывод: линия метро → метролиния, станция метро → метростанция. Из книги "Чайки над Каспием" (примечания): *Подразумевается **метростанция** Темпл*. *Подразумевается **метростанция** Холборн*.

Comment: Вот ещё: ***метропереход*** (https://books.google.ee/books?id=GSujAAAAQBAJ&pg=PT651&lpg=PT651&dq=%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4&source=bl&ots=jzs5K3ag32&sig=ACfU3U3vdtaiuBJtkjp5Gcf5atZVENs-dg&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi-mLTi25uCAxUAExAIHR7KAzU4ChDoAXoECAMQAw#v=onepage&q=%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4&f=false).

Comment: *Слова метростанция нет ни в каком словаре*. Но ведь слова ***метро-станция*** тоже нет ни в одном словаре... Да поправьте уже ж ответ, Максим! Будет красиво и правильно. Вы ведь проделами большую работу... Орфографический ***метропоезд*** (= поезд метро) Вам в помощь — для ускорения принятия решения... (http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B4)

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Поправил уже.